# reactjs will only call php script on every second submission

Tags: php, html, reactjs

I have an html page written in reactjs called index.html (see below). When the submission button is pressed it does a get request that that calls a php script called upload.php (see below). The html page passes the name of a file to be created by the php script via the get request. This file name is given to the html page by the user when they type in the field following the words "Enter File Name Here". The php script is supposed to create a file by the given name and put into the file the string "asdf".

This succeeds for me consistently on the first, third, fifth etc times that I press submit with a new file name. It never succeeds on the second, fourth sixth etc times that I press submit. I would like to stress that it does this consistently, that is to say, it is not random, it does in fact alternate between successfully generating the file and then not generating it.

If you have any ideas what is causing this and how to fix it please let me know. Thanks for your time.

below is upload.php:

```
<?php
$fileName = htmlspecialchars($_GET["fileName"]);
$myfile = fopen($fileName, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile,"asdf");
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

below is index.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">


class NameForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {fileName:""}
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    handleSubmit(){
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {}.bind(this)
        console.log("fileName = " + this.state.fileName)
        xmlHttp.open("GET","upload.php?fileName="+this.state.fileName,true)
        xmlHttp.send(null)
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            Enter File Name Here: <input type="text" value={this.state.fileName}
                        onChange={(event) => this.setState({fileName: event.target.value})}/><br/>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></form><br/>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NameForm />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

</script>
</body>
```

@Tenza:

Thanks for your comment, I have looked at the network tab while running my code and this is what happened. These are pictures of my network tab when submitting test3 and test4.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDDAl.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBC5F.jpg

test3 was not successful however test4 was successful (This is because I skipped test 1 by accident)

Note that the message in the network tab quickly disappeared so I was unable to view it directly, I had to take a video of it and then take a screen shot of the video.

If you have any ideas what is happening here please let me know, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to post this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

What comes up on the network tab when you do these actions of the 2nd, 4th etc. Is the request being sent? If it does succeed then the PHP code may be failing somewhere check for example $fileName first, this may be an issue with asynchronous function.

Comment: @fred You may want to add the event parameter e and set e.preventDefault() to the handleSubmit function to stop the page from reloading so you can see the request. Then in your PHP debugger check what the value of $fileName is.